# SQL ERD how to relate this two sets

Tags: sql, erd

I have two tables, "patients" and "doctors", where idPatient and idDoctor are primary keys respectively.

The thing is I want to relate this two table in a way that:

- One patient can have more than one doctor.
- One doctor can have more than one patient.

At the same time, it could happen that one patient have no relationship with any doctor and, similarly, one doctor don't have relationship with any patient.

How is declared this in SQL? (I'm using PostgreSQL)

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homework question....
You have a many to many relationship (m:n) so have a search on how to model those

Comment: Implement a DoctorPatientRelationships Table, that has both an idDoctor and an idPatient field.  This functionality can also be supported by a Consultations Table that also has both keys.

Comment: I have done this, to implement a doctorpatientrelationship table. The problem is there are many other tables with this kind of relationship, so I would need to create a lot of auxiliar tables, I don't know if this is a best practice that's why I asked for a way to declare that in SQL in a more best practice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a separate table for the relationships.  It might be defined something like this:

```
create table patientDoctors (
     patientDoctorId int generated always as identity,
     patientId int references patients(patientId),
     doctorId int references doctors(doctorId)
);
```

You might have additional information in the table such as:

- The date when the relationship was started.
- The "source" of the relationship.
- And so on.

Comment: Thanks! This kind of relationships take into account that could be that one doctor have no patients and one patient have no doctors, I guess.

Comment: @Miquel . . . Yes.  There can be rows in `patients` and `doctors` with no corresponding rows in `patientDoctors`.